# Do you know how to do an inverted mask/shader or any other way to see onlu part of an object within a sphere boundary in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, stencil-buffer, urp

Cut out sphere

[image: 1]

What im looking for it this exactly behaviour but what i need is that is compatible with URP, as you may see im just starting with Shaders

could you give me any guidance on how to update this to URP?

i have look up for stencil shader / cut out / Buffer

i have replicated the portal stile ones but i need the object to be able to grow like a tree but if its outside the sphere should not show

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [Sphere Mask node](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.shadergraph@12.1/manual/Sphere-Mask-Node.html) :

[image: Example of Sphere Mask]

And link `Out` to the Alpha property (if your `Surface Type` is set to `Opaque` then, check the `Alpha Clipping` in your Graph settings).